# jquery scroll code not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating scrolling to particular location of the elements by clicking on the menu links

Html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#1" class="scroll">1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#2" class="scroll">2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#3" class="scroll">3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#4" class="scroll">4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- header -->
<div class="row sections">
    <div class="container"> <a name="1"></a>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Div 1</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row sections">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> <a name="2"></a>

                <h1>Div 2</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row sections">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> <a name="3"></a>

                <h1>Div 3</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row sections">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12"> <a name="4"></a>

                <h1>Div 4</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery for the above code

```
$(function () {
    $("a.scroll").click(function () {
        if (this.hash) {
            //get rid of hash
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

            //get the position of the <a name> 
            var $toElement = $("a[name=" + hash + "]");
            var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

            //scroll/animate that element
            $("body,html").animate({

                scrollTop: toPosition

            }, 500, "easeOutExpo");

            //don't do the jump
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (location.hash) {
        var hash = location.hash;
        window.scroll(0, 0);
        $("a[href=" + hash + "]").click();
    }
});
```

Using bootstrap i have fixed my navbar and having 4 links to scroll at 4 particular locations and trying to scroll the page to particular element with hash method but my scrolling not working properly and easing also not working properly when i am trying to scroll by clicking the elements its not scrolling and not even showing any error.

And if i am putting the semi-colon after the animate position method its working scrolling but not in a animated way,

So how to fix it so that i can scroll to particular locations of the page.

Comment: any live example to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Instead of using `.position`, for your case it would be better to use `.offset().top`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to cancel the default property of clicking on a hash link.

Try the following js

```
$(function () {
    $("a.scroll").click(function (e) {
        if (this.hash) {
            //get rid of hash
            var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

            //get the position of the <a name> 
            var $toElement = $("a[name=" + hash + "]");
            var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

            //scroll/animate that element
            $("body,html").animate({

                scrollTop: toPosition

            }, 500, "easeOutExpo");

            //don't do the jump
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (location.hash) {
        var hash = location.hash;
        window.scroll(0, 0);
        $("a[href=" + hash + "]").click();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$toElement.offset().top` to get the target's position.

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/cexabeqimiro/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
$("a.scroll").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.hash) {
        //get rid of hash
        var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

        //get the position of the <a name> 
        var $toElement = $("a[name=" + hash + "]");
        var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top;

        //scroll/animate that element
        $("body").animate({

            scrollTop: toPosition

        }, 500);

    }
});
```

Comment: it seems to be working properly now, thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. `element.position()`only gives you the offset *relative to the parent*.

Logging it to the console then gave `-13px` for all your divs.

Use `element.offset()` instead:

```
var toPosition = $toElement.offset().top;
```

Link to working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/Lbr0s80m/1/